# MappingExpection NHibernate 4 .net 4.5 SPA

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, single-page-application

I've tried a 1000 different options an permutations.
Why can't compile my Cat mapping?

Exception thrown: 'NHibernate.MappingException' in NHibernate.dll
Additional information: Could not compile the mapping document: (string)

```
        Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
        cfg.Configure();
        cfg.AddXmlString(
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf - 8"" ?>"
            + @"<hibernate-mapping xmlns=""urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"" assembly=""QuickStart"" namespace=""QuickStart.Cat"">"
            + @"<class name=""Cat"" table=""Cat"">"
            + @"  <id name=""Id"" ><column name=""CatId"" /><generator class=""uuid.hex"" /></id>"
            //+ @"  <id name=""Id"" ><column name=""CatId"" sql-type=""char(32)"" not-null=""true"" /><generator class=""uuid.hex"" /></id>"
            //+ @"  <property name=""Name"" ><column name=""Name"" length=""16"" not-null=""true"" /></property>"
            //+ @"  <property name=""Sex"" />"
            //+ @"  <property name=""Weight"" />"
            + @"</class>"
            + @"</hibernate-mapping>"
        );
```

--- from Web.Config
    
      
    
    
      
        NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
        NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
        NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect
        Server=localhost;initial catalog=PlaygroundDB;Integrated Security=True

Comment: I think the answer is already given below, but just an additional note: Always check the exception message including recursively the InnerException property - this is usually quite helpful.

Comment: "Could not compile" is as close to the inner exception as nhibernate is presenting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`encoding=""utf - 8"" ?>` should be `encoding=""utf-8""?>`

But I never add xml mapping programmaticaly one by one. And even less as raw string (which is quite prone to errors). Instead, I add `ClassName.hbm.xml` files in project, setting their `Build action` property to `Embedded resource`, and I call `.AddAssembly(MyProjectAssembly)` before building the configuration.

If your mappings are embedded in the same assembly defining your session factory, the code is as simple as:

```
public static class NHibernateSessionFactory
{
    private static readonly ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    static NHibernateSessionFactory()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.Configure();
        configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(NHibernateSessionFactory).Assembly);
        _sessionFactory = configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISessionFactory Instance { get { return _sessionFactory; } }
}
```

Minimal configuration file (hibernate.cfg.xml) I am using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration  xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory name="ProjectName">
    <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string_name">ProjectConnectionStringName</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect</property>
    <property name="adonet.batch_size">100</property>
    <property name="prepare_sql">true</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`ProjectConnectionStringName` refers to a connection string defined in .Net standard configuration `connectionStrings` node.

Comment: According to nHibernate's documentation and construction there are maybe 12 different ways of adding mappings to the configuration. But if one works they should all work alike.  Pursuant to my original post I'm finding embedded resource to have some help.  But embedded resource isn't a complete resolution.  And as I said I've tried one thousand things ~ I literally meant it.  I have literally tried everything within the nHibernate space.

Comment: My point was to advise a simpler setup for debugging your troubles. And to point the fact that `utf - 8` is invalid, thus probably causing this generic error you have seen, hiding by the way any other error your mapping may contain. If the xml is invalid, it cannot be interpreted.

Comment: Well thanks for the advice and finding the extra spaced the in UTF spec.  Fixing the UTF spec did change anything.

Comment: Well thanks for the advice and finding the extra spaced the in UTF spec.  Fixing the UTF spec didn't change anything either way good or bad.  The problem apears to be that AddFile() can't find the file no matter how literal you are.  I found that if I don't define the configuration in Web.config the hibernate.cfg.xml has to be in the bin folder.  Unfortunately this isn't even true for the <mapping>.hbm.xml files.  Personally I believe "Embedded Resource" is contrary to flexibility and good application management.
Sadly, the embedded option seems to be the only way to make nHibernate work.

Comment: For `hibernate.cfg.xml`, set its `Build Action` property in project to `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer`or `Copy always`. (This is a bit redundant but well, I do not care.) Regarding mappings, I do not see them as configuration files: changing them usually involve code changes. In such case, re-building is required, so having them as embedded resources is not an issue. Regarding `AddFile`, it should work. [It looks like it works for others](/q/702195/1178314). Ask another question on that subject with your specific details if it is not the case for you.